# Why does this src of an img tag in pug gives an error?

Tags: node.js, pug

```
img(src="../img/logo.png" alt="log")
```

this is how my img tag looks like.

```
-img(folder)
   -logo.png(file)

-pug(folder)
   -index.pug(file)
```

localhost/:16 GET http://localhost:3000/img/logo.png 404 (Not Found)
And this is the error message.

pls help me.

Comment: Not that familiar with Pug; are you allowed to walk upwards in the directory structure from your root document?

Answer (score 0):

The default node/express installation has a folder called "public".  Move the "img" folder into there and the server will be able to send that file out to the browser.